# Trimmed input value displayed in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have an unknown number of input boxes with unknown IDs. I would like to be able to click on an input box and have a trimmed version of the value populate a div.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDrF7/)**

My code all works as expected once the input field is edited, but **I want to have the value displayed on first click/focus**.

This is the JS function I wrote.

**JS**

```
$('input').each(function() {
        var $tthis = $(this),
            defaultValue = $tthis.val();

 defaultValue = defaultValue.substring(keyed.indexOf("|") + 1);
 defaultValue = defaultValue.substring(0, defaultValue.length - 2)
        $("#target").html(defaultValue);    

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input
id='thistext$index'
type='text'
onclick='this.select();'
onfocus="
document.getElementById('show_hide').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('show_hide2').innerHTML = 'Copy this text into the wiki, it will display as: ';"
onblur="document.getElementById('show_hide').style.display='none';" value='&#91&#91;http://www.example.com/$dirArray[$index]&#124;$dirArray[$index]&#93;&#93;' />

<div id='show_hide'>
    <div id='show_hide2'>
    </div>
    <div id='target'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restructured your code a bit from the first fiddle.
I threw out all inline javascript and it's handlers, the `onFocus, onBlur, onClick` and replaced with jQuery equivalents and I think I got what you wanted.

I used jQuery's `on()` method to do the same thing which cleaned up the HTML a lot.
Then I used a function within `show()` to trigger a few other functions.
This could be more procedural but I thought it was nice and clean.

And lastly I extracted out the trimming and substringing to it's own function so that you can reuse it later on.

[A fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KDrF7/4/) and the code below:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    $('#show_hide').show(function(){
        $('#show_hide2').text('Copy this text into the wiki, it will display as:');
        var text = trimInputValue($input);
        $('#target').text(text);
    });
});

function trimInputValue($input) {
    var text = $input.val();
    text = text.substring(text.indexOf("|") + 1);
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
    return text;
}

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
    $('#show_hide').hide();
});
```

Now you might wonder where your `select()` went off to.
Don't worry, just include it in your `on('click', function(){ select(); });` and it should execute.